# How to create object using this given constructor

Tags: java, object, constructor, new-operator, super

```
public Life(List<class> classes, int schoolwork) {
        super(classes, schoolwork);
    }
```

I am trying to make a Life object out of this code but am not doing it right what I have is

```
Life life = new Life();
```

but I can't figure out how to get the parameters right to include classes and schoolwork.

Comment: Are you sure you can do this: `List<class>`? Can you post the whole code please?

Comment: yes I am sure I can. I just need to know what goes in the parameters for objects for something like this in general I guess

Comment: @RooseveltJames `class` is a keyword, and so can't be used as a type parameter. Do you mean `Class` (capital C). Otherwise, can you show how `class` is declared?

Comment: oh yess im sorry I meant Class

Comment: `Life life = new Life(Collections.emptyList(), 0);` is one valid invocation.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to interpret your problem and I wrote a piece of code where I show you how to create a `Life` object by passing it the correct parameters.

Maybe your problem was creating the `List` object (?)

**CODE**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<CustomClass> customClass = new ArrayList<>();
        int schoolwork = 1;

        Life life = new Life(customClass, schoolwork);
    }

}

class CustomClass {
}

class Life {

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param customClass
     * @param schoolwork
     */
    public Life(List<CustomClass> customClass, int schoolwork) {
        // super(strings, schoolwork);
    }

}
```